# DBUnit - Hibernate - org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate dialect class

Tags: hibernate, junit, mockito, powermock, dbunit

I try to use Integration testing my class with JUNit, DBUnit and Hibernate.

### For the initialization of the database

To simulate an isolated database, I used this [tutorial](http://www.inspire-software.com/en/index/view/articles-design-and-impl-dbunit-hibernate-integration-testing.html).

Note that I had to create two HibernateUtil class (one (named `HibernateUtils.class`) based on the tutorial which allowed me to set where `hibernate.test.cfg.xml` is located, the other one (named `HibernateSessionFactory` which created the SessionFactory based on `hibernate.cfg.xml` )

### Integration Testing

I have to test the `show_Potions()` method from `Player.class`.

`show_Potions()` set the potions of the player based on a query from the database. I want the test to make queries in the isolated database not the real database so I proceed that way: when the `HibernateSessionFactory.configureSessionFactory()` is used, we use 'HibernateUtils.newSessionFactory("hibernate.test.cfg.xml")`.

I got the exception :

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:82)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:64)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
at test.HibernateUtils.newSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.java:27)
at test.HibernateDbUnitTestCase.setUp(HibernateDbUnitTestCase.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:73)
... 37 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.HibernateDbUnitTestCase.tearDown(HibernateDbUnitTestCase.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runAfters(MethodRoadie.java:149)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

You can see the codes below.

Thank you for your reply. If you have another way to access the isolated database, I'd be glad to hear it.

---

### Player.class

```
public class Player extends TablePlayer {

    private List<Item> items;

    //other attributes…

    /*
     * This method set the list of potions of the player based on the query from the database.
     */

    public void show_Potions() throws Exception {

        SessionFactory sf = HibernateSessionFactory.configureSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        try {

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("from TableItems items " +
                    "left join fetch items.name " +
                    "left join fetch items.type " +
                    "left join fetch items.idPlayer player " +
                    "where player.id = :pid ");
            query.append("order by items.dateObtained desc");

        List<TableItems> tableItems = session.createQuery(query.toString()).setParameter(“pid”, this.getId()).list();

        List<Item> potions = new ArrayList<Items>();

        for(TableItems tItem : tableItems){
            Item item = new Item(tItem);
            if(item.getType()).equals(“POTION”){
                potions.add(item);
            }       
        }

        this.setItems( potions );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }       
    }

    /*
     *  Constructor
     */


    public Player(String id) { // Create a player based on the ID found in the Database
    }

    // other methods...

}
```

---

### PlayerTest

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(HibernateSessionFactory.class)
public class PlayerTest extends HibernateDbUnitTestCase {

    private Player player
    private Player player_to_spy;
    private List<Item> actual_items;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        player_to_spy = new Player(“1”);
        player = spy(player_to_spy);
        actual_items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {  
           return new FlatXmlDataSet(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test/database.xml"));
        }  


    @Test
    public void testShow_Potions() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(HibernateSessionFactory.class);
        Mockito.when(HibernateSessionFactory.configureSessionFactory()).thenReturn(sessionFactory);     // sessionFactory is an attribute of HibernateDbUnitTestCase
        Mockito.when(HibernateSessionFactory.configureSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session); //session is an attribute of HibernateDbUnitTestCase

        player.setId(“1”);      
        player.show_Potions();
        actual_items = player.getItems(); // return the list of items.

        List<Items> expected_items = new ArrayList<Items>();

        Item item1 = new item(“1”); // create an Item of id n°1 based on the database
        expected_items.add(item1);

        assertThat(actual_items,isEqualTo(expected_items)); // I’ve written the isEqualTo() method.
    }

    @After
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        player_to_spy = null;
        player = null
        actual_items = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up finding the solution of this issue.

The problem was that I created two SessionFactory in my test. 
i.e : When I call `show_potions()` in the test, I call `HibernateSessionFactory.configureSessionFactory()`. However, the test extends HibernateDBUnitTestCase whose `setUp()` method calls `HibernateUtils.newSessionFactory()`. Thus, the test didn't know what hibernate configuration it should use.

With this method, you won't need PowerMock and you must use JUnit3 since DBunit is based on that. Thus, you must change @Test, @Before and @After with what it is required in Junit3.

This is how I solve the problem.

### 1) Modify HibernateSessionFactory:

The initial version was :

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;


static {
    try {
        // Create sessionFactory based on hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

I **removed the static block and changed the configureSessionFactory()** with the following :

```
public static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

I've also added this method.

```
public static void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) 
{ 
    HibernateSessionFactory.sessionFactory = factory; 
}
```

**2) Modify HibernateDbUnitTestCase**

In the setUp, I added the following line:

```
if (sessionFactory == null) {  
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtils.newSessionFactory("hibernate.test.cfg.xml");  
        HibernateSessionFactory.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    }
```

And that was all, whenever the 'real' program calls `show_potions()`, `HibernateSessionFactory.configureSessionFactory(`) uses `"hibernate.cfg.xml"`, and when the test program calls show_potions, it uses `"hibernate.test.cfg.xml"`.

I hope it will help other people.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty explicit about what the problem is.

Check your configuration and verify that you've properly configured the dialect and that it is pointing to the proper dialect class name.  If it is, make sure that the dialect is actually on the classpath if it is a custom dialect implementation.

Comment: The dialect are on the classpath for sure. When I ran the test with the sample code provided by the tutoriel, it worked fine. (That means HSQLDialect.class if found) When I ran the test without the DBUnitTestcase (which means I worked with the real database) it also worked fine. (That means Oracle10gDialect.class is found too)

Comment: What version of Hibernate?